# Create a mesh around a group of animated empties?

Tags: mesh, scripting, objects, armature, add-on

I have a project with a bunch of animated empty objects in the form of a human body. I want to create a mesh around these so that there will be a generic human form animated. Is there any quick way to do this for a generic case through script or an add-on or feature? I want it to be automated so if I have many projects with different animations or empty formations I can quickly produce a mesh around these empties.

If there is no current add-on or script to do this, can anyone point me in the right direction such as steps or where might be a good place to start in creating this feature? I am aware that there are already add-ons that turn bones to mesh and now I want the equivalent to turn empties into one conjoined mesh.

Comment: It sounds as if you want a very fast method, and I don't think you will find one except through maybe a paid addon. That said, it might be possible to use the Skin modifier for doing something like this manually, where you create a simple starting object and delete all its parts except one edge or vertex, and then create a skin modifier on this object. With Vertex Snapping enabled, you could extrude a single mesh vertex to be snapped to each of these empties in turn, and in the process, create geometry of roughly the needed dimensions. Admittedly, this would be tedious.

Comment: @R-800 thanks for the idea - I'll look into using the Skin modifier, I think it will be helpful. I want to try to automate this process so from here, I'll probably try to create the mesh in script placing and connecting the vertices at the empty positions and then apply the skin modifier from there

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90171/how-to-transfer-an-animation-from-a-tree-of-empties-onto-an-armature-space-conv   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30835/convert-a-c3d-and-trc-files-to-bvh   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135824/copy-relative-positions-of-empties-to-bone-rotations-in-a-smaller-armature  Using the empties as constraint targets for a human rig would be my suggestion  (Use the mesh that comes with the rig)